Two Applications of Borel Cantelli Lemma
I am preparing for my exam in probability theory and i am struggeling with the following:
a)$(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ Probability Space, if $A_1,A_2,....\in \mathcal{F}$ are independent and $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=p_n$, then:$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{A_n}=+\infty)=1 \Leftrightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n=\infty $$
I have some problems to prove one side of this.
$"\Leftarrow"$
For $A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal{F}$ independent:  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\infty$ $\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(lim\text{ }sup\text{ } A_n)=1$
So there is $\mathbb{1}_{A_n}=1$ infinitely often.
$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{A_n}=+\infty)=1$
$"\Rightarrow"$ Here i dont know how to start, i hope someone can help!
b) $X_1,X_2,...$ i.i.d $X_1\sim\mathcal{U}[0,1]$
I have to determine $$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{X_n<1/n}=+\infty)$$
Well if i take $A_n=\{X_n<1/n\}$ then the $A_n$'s are independent since the $X_n$'s are independent and $p_n =\mathbb{P}(A_n)=1/n$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n=\infty$$ with a) follows that $$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{X_n<1/n}=+\infty)=1$$
Since i have proven this in a) i can leave it like this i guess.

We have $\sum_n 1_{A_n}=\infty$ if and only if $\limsup_n A_n,$ so both directions are immediate consequences of the BC lemma and the converse BC lemma. For the direction you're asking about, if $\sum_np_n < \infty,$ then the BC lemma says $P(\limsup_nA_n) = 0$ so $P(\sum_n 1_{A_n}=\infty) = 0 \ne 1$ (no independence needed for this direction.)
You are correct for part b.
